# How to check for empty JSON string in RouteOnContent in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am attempting to execute some SQL using some extracted values. In some cases I get data back and in others I get null. For the null cases, I want to route them, so looked at using `RouteOnContent` after converting them from `Avro` to `JSON`.

However, I do not know what "property" to check against. The `RouteOnContent` processor asks you for a property name and a value for which to check against, and in this case I will not have any property, because the entirety of the data will be `{}`

How might I evaluate to get a value to check for `{}` to route accordingly? Can I even use `Avro` instead?

Flow:

[image: flow]

Comment: I realize of course that after having received `{}` back from the query I would not be able to do anything further anyway. I think what I will need to do is create a different JSON with the original values used for the `ExecuteSQL` -- so something like this: `{"results" : {}, "color": "yellow", "year": 1995}` -- and then check against the `results` property

Answer (score 1):

I ended up discovering that `ExecuteSql` can actually do upserts. I didn't think that was possible because for the query property it seems to allude to only select statements: [ExecuteSql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqyBG.png)

But I ended up putting in an upsert anyway, after an `EvaluateJson` and was successful. Here is the final flow: [final_flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv0Cx.png)

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteSQL writes an attribute `executesql.row.count` that will tell you how many rows are returned - so use `RouteOnAttribute` on this attribute.

You can see what Attributes a processor returns in the [docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html) in the `Writes Attributes` section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My fault -- I failed to mention the count was a property of a previous query from Kafka, not a result of ExecuteSql. I have renamed it `yc_count` in my new `ExecuteSQL` query to avoid confusion.